# How to Merge MySQL tables without Primary Keys and by prioritizing one over the other based on 3 columns?

Tags: mysql, merge

I have an old version of a MySQL table (OLD) with the following columns:

```
countrycode      varchar(2)
postalcode       varchar(20)
placename        varchar(180)
adminname1       varchar(100)
admincode1       varchar(20)
adminname2       varchar(100)
admincode2       varchar(20)
adminname3       varchar(100)
admincode3       varchar(20)
latitude         decimal(10.7)
longitude        decimal(10.7)
accuracy         tinyint(1)
```

This table does not have a primary key.

I also have a newer version (NEW) of this table with the same structure above where some of the data has been updated.

I want to merge the two tables in such a way where I get a new table (MERGED) that includes the results from both, but if there is a clash such that NEW.countrycode = OLD.countrycode and NEW.postalcode = OLD.postalcode and NEW.placename = OLD.placename, then I want the row from NEW table data to take precedence as it has more up-to-date lat/long data.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general (extendable) format of the queries you'll need. *Notice the second query uses the target table to filter it's values; you could continue with t0, tminus1, tminus2, etc... if needed.*

```
INSERT INTO tNew(f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3)
SELECT f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3
FROM t2
;
INSERT INTO tNew(f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3)
SELECT f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3
FROM t1
WHERE (t1.f1, t1.f2, t1.f3) NOT IN (
  SELECT f1, f2, f3
  FROM tNew
)
;
```

With just two tables, it can be done in a single query (but notice the second part must now use the first part's table to filter, rather than the target table).

```
INSERT INTO tNew(f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3)
SELECT f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3
FROM t2
UNION
SELECT f1, f2, f3, g1, g2, g3
FROM t1
WHERE (t1.f1, t1.f2, t1.f3) NOT IN (
  SELECT f1, f2, f3
  FROM t2
)
;
```

In these general solutions I am using `f[number]` to informally denote the "row identifying" fields (in this case `countrycode`, `postalcode`, `placename`); and `g[number]` to denote "detail" fields (in this case "lat/long data").

---

The concept behind both of these suggestions is to use the data from the table with the most precedence first, then fill in the data that was not in it with the less precedent tables.

...if you just want to keep the most precedent table and fill its "blanks" in with older tables, you can just use the second query from my first suggestion; in that case `tNew` would be the table you want to keep, and `t1` would be the older table you are using to complete the newer table's data.

Comment: If the `countrycode` `postalcode`  and `placename` are what make a row "unique" and all other 9 columns are the details that would need to be updated from the `NEW` table, how would your code look?

Comment: The same; you'd just replace f1, f2, and f3 with countrycode, postalcode, and placename respectively; and replace g1, g2, g3 with the other 9 columns. Your use of the word "update" suggests I should I'll add a little explanation to what this answer is doing, see edit I just added below the dividing line in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new table named newtable

Join two old tables, and get the most recent result oldtable2 or first value oldtable1

Finally use the select to insert the values in newtable

```
INSERT INTO newtable (
   SELECT 
   IFNULL(oldtable2.field1, oldtable1.field1) AS field1,
   IFNULL(oldtable2.field2, oldtable1.field2) AS field2
   FROM oldtable1 
   LEFT JOIN oldtable2 ON
      oldtable1.field1=oldtable2.field1 AND
      oldtable1.field2=oldtable2.field2 AND
      ...
)
```